# Loading local images in Codename One Project

Tags: codenameone

I've got a database, and each entity has a certain number of photographs.

I want to load these images in a component, and form what I've found I can in a Multi-List. I'm having problems as I don't know how to do this.

The database currently hold the paths of the images, which I have placed in a folder next to my src.

I know I should be pasting here what I have tried, but nothing I have tried has been successful in the least.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks,
Ari.

Comment: How are the images stored within the database? Are they links to URL's to files on the harddrive? If the former you should check ImageDownloadService and the FacebookDemo where this is used.
Do you actually have an Image object or is that also a problem?

Comment: Shai! So awesome you replied :D. Yes the links are on the hard drive. I didn't know there was a Facebook demo. I'm sure I'll find everything I need there. I'll get back to you here as soon as I can tomorrow. I'm going to watch the demo now. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Shai. I'm looking for that FacebookDemo. I can't seem to find it. Could you help me out? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.codenameone.com/download.html scroll down, docs & demos download includes a facebook demo.